# Android Studio remember the player progress

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a small problem. How i can set up my code for - when the user complete the "x" level then when he opens an app in for example 2 days he will get that level completed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharedpreferences to store data and later you can get data from this sharedpreferences in order to check on which level user should be.

Check this: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences